# vba function to copy a cell and pastespecial to the active cell where I write =macrofunction

Tags: vba, excel

In making a vba function I want to simply copy one fixed cell and pastespecial its value to the highlighted cell(selected cell wehere I enter macro function) in the same worksheet. This works when I run the macro from within the editor but making the macro with a formula doesn't work for pasting the cell to the cell I am writing the function in. If I write in C2 =macropasteC1
where my macro is called macropastec1
I get #NAME and not the number in C1
although when I run the macro with c2 selected in vba editor it did work although I lost the exact formula

it was something like

```
 'Sub macropastec1()

   macropastec1 Macro

  Selection.Copy
  cell("C1").Select
 active.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues**,Operation:=xlNone,SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False**
End Sub`
```

I can't remember exactly how I had it like range.(C1).select 
but it was similar to above. I started by recording it and then I did insert macro copied it and changed sub to function to get the macro function

please help I really need this ability

Another variation that worked in the editor for activating a cel and running from in the editor I think was

```
 'function macropastec1()

   macropastec1 Macro

  Selection.Copy
  range.("C1").Select
 activecell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues**,Operation:=xlNone,SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False**
End function`
```

obvioulsy because you need a macro function to run it from within a cell with =function

it is hard to replicate but I think the jist of what I am trying to achieve it clear

sorry this doesnt really answer but it does clarify whats being asked

the macro function in c1 if from a constantly changing cell is say c3
so in c1 I have

```
Function Min_Cell2(cx34 As Range)
'Function for defining the lowest number in a cell selected by the user

If Minimum <> "" Then
If Value_Range.Value < Minimum Then Minimum = Value_Range.Value
Else
Minimum = Value_Range.Value
End If

Min_Cell = Minimum

End Function
```

or the maximum equivalent. So I'd need it to paste special the value and not update it..

I assume chancea's function is this

```
Function macropastec2()
macropastec2 = Range("C1").Value
End Function
```

gives
upon entering in a cell =macropastec2(C1)

```
#VALUE

Function macropastec2() As varient
macropastec2 = Range("C1").Value
End Function
```

gives

```
#NAME
```

:S
If it helps I think the original function can be simplified to something like

```
'function macropastec1()

   macropastec1 Macro

  Selection.Copy
  range.("C1").Select
 activecell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues**,
End function`
```

Comment: If you want to call a sub procedure from writing in a cell, you would need to use the `Worksheet_Change` event and have that macro look for the text in the selected cell.

Comment: I don't know how to do that without hours of research but I don't think you understand. There will be no text in selected cell - it is empty waiting for a paste of the $C$1 cell upon writing =macropastec1. I will only select the cell to write =macropastec1 - thanks for replying

Comment: Any reason you can't just make the formula of the cell `=$C$1`?

Comment: yeh its slight complicated - I'm essentiall referecing a cell that is changing all the time and I need to copy if at specific period ie when another cell changes from non blank. Then once the cell pastes its value, the original cell will continue to change and I will have the pasted version of it at a specific time. The cell in question is coming from another vba I found -min_cell(C3) min_cell max_cell is somewhere online but if googled is a similar concept to what I am trying to achieve (ie function frm a maco) in active cell

Comment: are you just looking for something like `Function macropastec1() As Variant`
    `macropastec1 = Range("C1").Value`
`End Function`

Comment: not sure what this variant means? but I guess so .. actually no because the cell c1 is changing al the time.

Comment: Function Min_Cell2(cx34 As Range)
'Function for defining the lowest number in a cell selected by the user

If Minimum <> "" Then
    If Value_Range.Value < Minimum Then Minimum = Value_Range.Value
Else
    Minimum = Value_Range.Value
End If

Min_Cell = Minimum

End Function

Comment: @Jonwhite if you want the value to always update then Gary's solution will work.  I posted my code for taking a snapshot of the value.

Comment: thanks sorry I didn't see the last three comments. No as mentioned below I don't want the value to update  - I want it to be the equivalent of right click paste special value which gives the cell at the time you clicked pastespecial

Comment: @chancea oh so your takes a snapshot - I wil try it - yay hope - tried it and got #VALUE what I don't understand is it is refering to C1 twice now in your function :S

Comment: @Jonwhite im going to post an answer with some screenshots to show you what I am saying then

Comment: @Jonwhite oh. you just updated your question.  Yeah just call `=macropastec1()` no `c1` in the brackets

Comment: @chancea ok thanks  !I tried it for nothing in the brackets and I still  just get #NAME

Comment: You can't *select* a cell in a UDF.

Comment: @David Zemens- there must be a way to work around this though eg create hotkey to run sub macro. if(blank cell,hotkey, or something I just can't accept that this can't be done. I am going to print the macro everytime a new line is made in a column and I need this

Comment: A macro with a hot key could do it but NOT a UDF.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function:

```
Function macropastec1() As Variant
    macropastec1 = Range("C1").Value
End Function
```

If you need to specify a specific sheet you can add that in the function:

```
Function macropastec1() As Variant
    macropastec1 = Sheets("SheetName").Range("C1").Value
End Function
```

The VBA module should look like this:
[image]

This function will **not** update the cell value when you change `C1`.

You use it in any cell by calling:

```
=macropastec1()
```

## Demonstration:

1) Enter `=macropastec1()` in cell A1:
[image]

2a) If we change C1:

[image]

2b) A1 does **not** change:

[image]

3a) If we now enter `=macropastec1()` in A2:

[image]

3b) We see the new value, while the first value stays the same:

[image]

Comment: I got 0 when I tried this in A1 but C1 is a positive number

Comment: @Jonwhite Are you staying within the same sheet?

Comment: I am yes it just gives 0 although oddly when I edit it eg the C1 reference it does move to another sheet

Comment: @Jonwhite it will only give you 0 if `C1` is empty at the time you type in the formula and press enter...

Comment: I dont understand then because the     C1 is populated with a number all the time.

Comment: @Jonwhite and I just noticed your suggested edit (probably best to update your question with information like that)  However if _that_ was the code you are using then you will get 0 because copying and pasting within a macro is usually done by a `sub` not a `function` subs you run using the macro run, functions you can call using the `=FunctionName()`

Comment: @Jonwhite thats what I was asking, if you need to reference a _specific_ sheet name then you need to change the function to `Sheets("SheetName").Range("C1").Value`

Comment: ok gr8 I think this works ! Ill let you know very soon when cell value changes - YES this has worked beautifully thanks alot chancea. I assume this function will work inside an if function .. :D ahh it doesn't pleasingly

Comment: onto my next question how to reset a function , UDF, from a macro - shouldn't be too tricky

Answer (score 1):

> In making a vba function I want to simply copy one fixed cell and
>   pastespecial its value to the highlighted cell in the same worksheet.

In a *Standard Module* include the following:

```
Public Function macropastec1(r As Range)
    macropastec1 = r.Value
End Function
```

You would use it the worksheet like:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If **you** want to control the copy/paste, use a **Sub** rather than a *UDF()*
In the same standard module include the following **Sub**:

```
Public Sub macropastSC1()
    Range("C1").Copy
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

1. the sub only runs when you decide to run it
2. you must first select the destination cell
3. if **C1** contains a *formula* the destination cell will get the value.

**REMEMBER**:
A *UDF* in a worksheet cell can only return a value to the cell in which it resides.  It cannot make changes to other cells in the worksheet.

Comment: ok which variation of the original function attempted should I use in combination with this. Hang on I need to replicate what I described originally first - is this to invite two macro names trhe same thing :s

Comment: @Jonwhite .............if you use the *UDF()* that I posted, there is no need for any copying or pasting....

Comment: ok I tried this and this isnt what I want becasue the cell value still changes. If I had right clicked on C1 and selected paste special values the value would stay permanent

Comment: I have just confirmed this didn't work through testing. can't you change that to pastespeical.r.value paste value or something

Comment: I think this might boil down to can I run a sub as a function

Comment: I tried Public Function macropastSC3()
    Range("C1").Copy
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Function      selected a cell and pressed the play button in editor and it pasted like I'd like it to only it left the dancing ants around C1. Also I can't do =macropastSC3(C3) or just =macropastSC3() it gives me error

Comment: @Jonwhite  You are seeing a limitation of **VBA**  A function in a worksheet cell can't *Copy/Paste* elsewhere.....it can only return a value to the cell in which it resides.

Comment: how to I mark threads an answered I need to ask another question in a thread

Comment: @Jonwhite Just open a fresh, new question.